# curl --output command failing in CircleCI

Tags: curl, yaml, circleci

I have a simple config.yml file with the this content:

```
version: 2.1

parameters:
  project-url:
    type: string
    default: "none"

jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/project
    docker:
      - image: cimg/node:14.19.1
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Download Project File
          command: curl << pipeline.parameters.project-url >> --output build/tmp.zip
```

When I pass through a URL like this:

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/project.appspot.com/user_uploads/test/projects/test/project.zip?GoogleAccessId=project%40appspot.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=17017600&Signature=mNtazJLvfMXOw6rnzcxUCmgVU8prTGv%2dQcE5KCz4D08vHh3k%2B9ppsTmuW9WhpK8KA2UhDjohWjVq4ITGoOQ%2FRsw%2BFfdurVGGCD1am00FW%2FdEbRxgYiqEAcGW%2F9pAe%2FudeReWZNzZC8QGhVxBvlZ3Fm2HKTkGobRqOEVeayUV%2B8wiIJVCjnB9ewlE2WT8hYAJWXPd1Pm9Bcjd2RTiqmwhQ4%2Fe6xlWg7liexPJUEFCrft0YBJkbWWOjbzy8mp%2Fbsgjt%2B3iCMF2MF%2Fvh%2FuSUPCQ%3D%3D
```

I get an error: `/bin/bash: --output: command not found`

If I use an URL like this:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/project.appspot.com/o/user_uploads%2FnO1zNY9JO9boxQagw2%2Fprojects%2FCGzf6GM8g88YWC.zip\?alt\=media\&token\=e50cfa59-c723-488f-9d11-2c2ac7ac
```

Then I don't have any issues.

What could be the problem here? I have tried to encode/decode the URL, added parameters at the end so it doesn't end in "==", and many other things.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Have you tried enclosing double-quotes: `curl "<< pipeline.parameters.project-url >>" --output build/tmp.zip`?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to yaningo:

Parameters needed to be enclosed in double quotes.

`curl "<< pipeline.parameters.project-url >>" --output build/tmp.zip`